# Bind Objects of ObservableCollection to a DataGrid c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

i got a problem in WPF.

i got a DataGrid like:

```
DataGrid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="DataGridOverview" MinHeight="250" MinWidth="705"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle}" >
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" MinWidth="100" Header="Name" Binding="{Binding (clientsideFileManager:CfmModel+FileInformationForOverview.Name)}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="1*" MinWidth="50" Header="Größe" Binding="{Binding (clientsideFileManager:CfmModel+FileInformationForOverview.HumanReadableSize)}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="1*" MinWidth="70" Header="Typ" Binding="{Binding (clientsideFileManager:CfmModel+FileInformationForOverview.Type)}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="1*" MinWidth="70" Header="Status" Binding="{Binding (clientsideFileManager:CfmModel+FileInformationForOverview.Status)}"/>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Progress" Width="1*" MinWidth="70">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>

                                    <ProgressBar Name="progressBar"
                                                 Value="{Binding Path=(clientsideFileManager:CfmModel+FileInformationForOverview.ProgressValue), Mode=OneWay,  UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"

                                                 Minimum="0" Maximum="100" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="30" MinWidth="50" Header="%" Binding="{Binding (clientsideFileManager:CfmModel+FileInformationForOverview.ProgressValue)}" />
                        <DataGridHyperlinkColumn Width="320" Header="Deeplink" Binding="{Binding (clientsideFileManager:CfmModel+FileInformationForOverview.Deeplink)}">
                            <DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
                                <Style>
                                    <EventSetter Event="Hyperlink.Click" Handler="DG_Hyperlink_Click"/>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
                        </DataGridHyperlinkColumn>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

The Class Bind to the DataGrid is:

```
       public class FileInformationForOverview
    {
        public int IdOnList { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public Int64 Size { get; set; }
        public String HumanReadableSize { get; set; }
        public String Path { get; set; }
        public String Type { get; set; }
        public int ProgressValue { get; set; }
        public long JobId { get; set; }
        public Boolean IsChecked { get; set; }
        public cfmData CfmData { get; set; }
        public bool Paused { get; set; }
        public String Deeplink { get; set; }


        public String Status { get; set; }

        public String LastStatus { get; set; }
    }
```

In a List:

```
        public readonly ObservableCollection<CfmModel.FileInformationForOverview> OverviewList =
        new ObservableCollection<CfmModel.FileInformationForOverview>();
```

The List is in my MainWindow.xaml.cs, The Class FileInformationForOverview is in another Class (CFMModel.cs)

Its a Software to Upload Data. The User should see the Progress of each file in the DataGrid.

My Problem is, that I want to update the Progress the Update everytime it changed.

As i read in the Web the DataGrid Column should update everytime a binding changed. Did i do the Binding wrong?

I got the Refresh like that so far:

```
        public void model_OnProgressUpdate()
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action (()=>DataGridOverview.Items.Refresh()));
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => DataGridOverview.Focus()));
    }
```

But this blocks the GUI completely till the Upload is finished.

### Hope u guys can help me :)

EDIT:
My code changed to the following:

DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="DataGridOverview" MinHeight="250" MinWidth="705"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding OverViewList}" Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle}" >
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" MinWidth="100"     Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=(clientsideFileManager:CfmModel+FileInformationForOverview.Name),UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="1*" MinWidth="50" Header="Größe" Binding="{Binding Path=(clientsideFileManager:CfmModel+FileInformationForOverview.HumanReadableSize),UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="1*" MinWidth="70" Header="Typ" Binding="{Binding Path=(clientsideFileManager:CfmModel+FileInformationForOverview.Type),UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="1*" MinWidth="70" Header="Status" Binding="{Binding Path=(clientsideFileManager:CfmModel+FileInformationForOverview.Status),UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Progress" Width="1*" MinWidth="70">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>

                                    <ProgressBar Name="progressBar"
                                                 Value="{Binding Path=(clientsideFileManager:CfmModel+FileInformationForOverview.ProgressValue), Mode=OneWay,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"

                                                 Minimum="0" Maximum="100" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="30" MinWidth="50" Header="%" Binding="{Binding (clientsideFileManager:CfmModel+FileInformationForOverview.ProgressValue),UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        <DataGridHyperlinkColumn Width="320" Header="Deeplink" Binding="{Binding (clientsideFileManager:CfmModel+FileInformationForOverview.Deeplink),UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                            <DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
                                <Style>
                                    <EventSetter Event="Hyperlink.Click" Handler="DG_Hyperlink_Click"/>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
                        </DataGridHyperlinkColumn>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

Class with objects to show in DataGrid(in Class CFMModel.cs):

```
    public class FileInformationForOverview : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public int IdOnList { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public Int64 Size { get; set; }
        public String HumanReadableSize { get; set; }
        public String Path { get; set; }
        public String Type { get; set; }
        public long JobId { get; set; }
        public Boolean IsChecked { get; set; }
        public cfmData CfmData { get; set; }
        public bool Paused { get; set; }
        public String Deeplink { get; set; }
        public String Status { get; set; }
        public String LastStatus { get; set; }
        private int _progressValue;
        public int ProgressValue
        {
            get { return _progressValue; }
            set
            {
                _progressValue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ProgressValue");
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
    }
```

And the list the Objects are Stored in (in MainWindow.xam.cs):

```
public BindingList<CfmModel.FileInformationForOverview> _overviewList
=
        new BindingList<CfmModel.FileInformationForOverview>();
DataGridOverview.DataContext = this;
DataGridOverview.ItemsSource = OverviewList;
DataGridOverview.ItemsSource = _overviewList;
        public BindingList<CfmModel.FileInformationForOverview> OverviewList
    {
        get { return _overviewList; }
        set { _overviewList = value; }
    }
```

Now there aren't any exceptions, but there isn't a refresh neither.

All I change is, to Count FileInformationForOverview.ProgresValue +1 when a Chunk finished uploading.

Comment: the update trigger for the binding is on the lost focus ? why ? Also your class does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` which is useful to actually send ValueChanged event so the interface update.

Comment: I tried to use INotifyPropertyChanged on my class but theres an InvalidArgumentException everytime i try to add Something to my List(when the update should happen), telling me that a key is null. i proved it several times now and no value that is bound to the Datagrid is ever null. When i try to trace the exception VS tells me that the source cannot be found

Comment: your list also need to have a `{get;set;}` to be bindable

Comment: updated Code, still DataGrid won't show change on items

Comment: `ObservableCollection<T>` was perfect why the change to a `BindingList` ?. your dataContext should only be set in the windows constructor as `this.DataContext = this;` and not the datagrid. In XAML the progress bar bindign should be `Value="{Binding ProgressValue}"`

Comment: Ok what i did now: I changed the list back to ObservableCollection. Deleted the DataContexts in my XAML, and added DataGridOverview.DataContext = this. changed the Value binding thing. but it says : Progress value can not be resolved. I'm going nuts about this binding stuff

Comment: when i implement INotifyPropertyChanged the exception is getting thrown. System.ArgumentNullException : Key cannot be null...

Comment: Questions to the admins: why u delete the .net4.0 tag? i think this is important to know that i cant develop on .net 4.5

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement you dataclass like this:
this should work, also I assume that your acctual work must be done in a different thread:

```
await Task.Run(()=> Calculate());
```

here is the class

```
   public class FileInformationForOverview : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public int IdOnList { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public Int64 Size { get; set; }
        public String HumanReadableSize { get; set; }
        public String Path { get; set; }
        public String Type { get; set; }
        public long JobId { get; set; }
        public Boolean IsChecked { get; set; }
        public cfmData CfmData { get; set; }
        public bool Paused { get; set; }
        public String Deeplink { get; set; }
        public String Status { get; set; }
        public String LastStatus { get; set; }

        private int _progressValue;
        public int ProgressValue
        {
            get { return _progressValue; }
            set
            {
                _progressValue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: My Work is getting done in another thread. Its working in the background but the Progress isnt shown in the Grid. The Items that are added to the list are shown but the Progress information isnt getting updated over time. When i try to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged it gives an IllegalArgumentException, Key cannot be Null..
Can u explain me what i need to set for :DataContext and ItemsSource.
if i understood right the ItemsSource is my OverviewList and the DataContext should be my MainWindow class, correct?